# Yii2: How to sort a GridView's column that doesn't belong to its model

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, yii2, gii

I made a model and its CRUD using Gii from a table called **vacations**. Its index.php has a GridView with two columns called **Column 1** and **Column 3**. Then I added a column called **Person** that come from a table called **persons**.

[image: GridView]

The problem is that the column **Person** is not sortable.

So I have this tables (**column1_id** and **person_id** are primary key of their tables):

```
vacations: column1_id, column3.
persons: person_id, person_name, column1_id.
```

Maybe I have to add something in the VacationsSearch file.

Comment: use relations. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32188-cgridview-to-display-data-from-two-tables/

Answer (score 1):

essentially you should  extend you search function for adding the query and sort   for the related  column

```
   $dataProvider->setSort([
       .....
          'your_related_column' => [
              'asc' => ['related_table.your_related_column' => SORT_ASC],
              'desc' => ['related_table.your_related_column' => SORT_DESC],
              'label' => 'Your Label'
          ]
      ]
  ]);

   .....

  // filter by country name
  $query->joinWith(['yor_relation' => function ($q) {
      $q->where('related_table.your_related_column LIKE "%' . $this->yourRelatedAttribute . '%"');
  }]);
```

for a wider  explanation you can see the scenario 2 of this example  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/